# Java exception ,linkage error when running application on WebSphere 9.0 with java 8

Tags: java, maven, java-8, websphere

I have setup a `WebSphere 9.0` instance with `java 8` . After uploading `.EAR` file and running my application , i can get lot of `IllegalStateException,CannotCompileException,LinkageError` . But it was working fine with JDK 1.6 . Am i missing anything in POM file or should i upgrade anything ?

This is the error log i am getting :

```
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp notifyServletContextCreated SRVE0283E: 
Exception caught while initializing context: {0} java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at java.lang.J9VMInternals.ensureError(J9VMInternals.java:141)
        at java.lang.J9VMInternals.recordInitializationFailure(J9VMInternals.java:130)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:88)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:437)
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:126)
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:104)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:258)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:204)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)


Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: javassist.CannotCompileException: by java.lang.LinkageError: org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyCreatorSupport
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JavassistApplicationContext.<clinit>(JavassistApplicationContext.java:61)
        ... 114 more
Caused by: javassist.CannotCompileException: by java.lang.LinkageError: org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyCreatorSupport
        at javassist.ClassPool.toClass(ClassPool.java:1120)
        at javassist.ClassPool.toClass(ClassPool.java:1063)
        at javassist.ClassPool.toClass(ClassPool.java:1021)
        at javassist.CtClass.toClass(CtClass.java:1259)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JavassistApplicationContext.<clinit>(JavassistApplicationContext.java:59)
        ... 114 more
Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyCreatorSupport
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassImpl(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:346)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:283)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor17.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
        at javassist.ClassPool.toClass2(ClassPool.java:1133)
        at javassist.ClassPool.toClass(ClassPool.java:1114)
        ... 118 more
```

and the dependency POM file :

```
 <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>net.percederberg.grammatica</groupId>
                <artifactId>grammatica</artifactId>
                <version>1.4</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>net.percederberg.mibble</groupId>
                <artifactId>mibble</artifactId>
                <version>2.8</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>net.percederberg.mibble</groupId>
                <artifactId>mibble-mibs</artifactId>
                <version>2.8</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
                <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.1</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>net.sf.jradius</groupId>
                <artifactId>jradius-client</artifactId>
                <version>20040211</version>
            </dependency>

            <!-- spring modules in alphabetic order -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-asm</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <!-- spring (former acegi) security -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-security-ldap</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <!-- spring-ws -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-ws-core</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-ws.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-ws-security</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-ws.version}</version>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>com.sun.xml.wsit</groupId>
                        <artifactId>xws-security</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>com.sun.xml.wsit</groupId>
                        <artifactId>wsit-rt</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>
            <!-- commons in alphabetic order -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
                <version>1.4</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
                <version>2.5</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.1</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.2</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
                <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
                <version>4.2.5</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
                <version>1.4</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
                <version>1.8.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-discovery</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-discovery</artifactId>
                <version>0.4</version>
            </dependency>

            <!-- DAO hibernate related -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
                <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.2.GA</version>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
                        <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
                <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
                <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
                <version>3.19.0-GA</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>antlr</groupId>
                <artifactId>antlr</artifactId>
                <version>2.7.7</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>stax</groupId>
                <artifactId>stax-api</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.ws.xmlschema</groupId>
                <artifactId>xmlschema-core</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.3</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
                <artifactId>jsr250-api</artifactId>
                <version>1.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
                <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.16</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jmock</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmock-junit4</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
                <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
                <version>1.8.0</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.easymock</groupId>
                <artifactId>easymock</artifactId>
                <version>3.0</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
            <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
                <version>1.6.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
                <version>1.4.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
                <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.1</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.snmp4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>snmp4j</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.3</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.snmp4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>snmp4j-agent</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.5</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.octo.captcha</groupId>
                <artifactId>jcaptcha</artifactId>
                <version>1.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.ws.security</groupId>
                <artifactId>wss4j</artifactId>
                <version>1.6.5</version>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.opensaml</groupId>
                        <artifactId>opensaml</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.woodstox</groupId>
                <artifactId>wstx-asl</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.8</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj</groupId>
                <artifactId>saaj-impl</artifactId>
                <version>1.3.2</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.ws.commons.axiom</groupId>
                <artifactId>axiom-impl</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.8</version>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
                        <artifactId>geronimo-activation_1.1_spec</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
                        <artifactId>geronimo-javamail_1.4_spec</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
                        <artifactId>geronimo-stax-api_1.0_spec</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
                <version>2.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.12</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>xalan</groupId>
                <artifactId>xalan</artifactId>
                <version>2.7.1</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
                <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.2</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>xerces</groupId>
                <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
                <version>2.8.1</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
                <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
                <version>3.2-FINAL</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>jfree</groupId>
                <artifactId>jcommon</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.15</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>jfree</groupId>
                <artifactId>jfreechart</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.13</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.samba.jcifs</groupId>
                <artifactId>jcifs</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.6</version>
            </dependency>

            <!-- RSA Dependencies -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>ognl</groupId>
                <artifactId>ognl</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.2</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.axis</groupId>
                <artifactId>axis</artifactId>
                <version>1.4</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.axis</groupId>
                <artifactId>axis-jaxrpc</artifactId>
                <version>1.4</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.axis</groupId>
                <artifactId>axis-saaj</artifactId>
                <version>1.4</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>wsdl4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>wsdl4j</artifactId>
                <version>1.6.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>aopalliance</groupId>
                <artifactId>aopalliance</artifactId>
                <version>1.0</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>



  <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                       <!-- <version>2.3.2</version>-->
                <version>2.3.2</version>       
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <showDeprecation>${maven.compiler.showDeprecation}</showDeprecation>
                    <showWarnings>${maven.compiler.showWarnings}</showWarnings>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    <debug>${maven.compiler.debug}</debug>
                    <optimize>${maven.compiler.optimize}</optimize>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.12</version>
                <configuration>
                    <skipTests>${maven.test.skip}</skipTests>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.8</version>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>javadoc</goal>
                            <goal>test-javadoc</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>site</phase>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>attach-sources</id>
                        <phase>verify</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

I have added the `source` and `target` version to `1.8` in pom file for `java 1.8` . I don't know why these error coming . It was working fine with the `jdk 1.6`. How to solve this error ? Is this due to any dependencies ?
Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 3):

The error occurs when the same class had been loaded by different class loaders. Probably, one ore more jars in your app, are already exist in web app server. Usually, web application servers use multiple class leaders, and you may see this type of error. To understand what is really happening, enable debugging on class loading. Here is a very good tutorial on the same https://vcfvct.files.wordpress.com/2015/06/do-you-really-get-classloaders.pdf

Comment: How to solve this class loader problem ? because my app is not started yet . I am getting these errors when i tried to start application .

Comment: You need to trace class loading and check what is happening when the error occurs. Here is how you can trace class loading for WS, https://sanjitmohanty.wordpress.com/2012/02/14/enabling-traces-for-debugging-class-loader-issues-in-websphere-application-server-6-1/    This happens when you include the same jar more than once, e.g. one in your app and one in web sphere lib. So you can compare the jars in there to the jars in your app and remove them from either your app or from app server lib.

Comment: ok thanks man . let me take the trace and i will update .

Comment: but this application was perfectly works with java 1.6 . why this is incompatible with java 8 ? any . suggestions ?

Comment: Yeah, this may happen if you compile the class with a newer java version and try to run it with an older java version. What is your java version on app server btw?

Comment: but if that is the case, you should also see this message, "Unsupported major.minor version"

Comment: both has java 8 . So i am deploying my java 1.8 JDK app to java 8 web sphere .

Comment: No idea, try collecting trace info.

Answer (score 1):

You are running at JVM 9
at java.lang.J9VMInternals.ensureError(J9VMInternals.java:141)

Comment: what does it mean ? i didn't get you . can you explain a little bit

Comment: For sure it is Java8 and don't be misleaded by IBM internal identifier like J9 (which is constant even in IBM java 6) java version "1.8.0"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build pxa6480sr3fp20ifix-20161110_01(SR3 FP20+IV90630+IV90578))
IBM J9 VM (build 2.8, JRE 1.8.0 Linux amd64-64 Compressed References 20161013_322271 (JIT enabled, AOT enabled)
J9VM - R28_Java8_SR3_20161013_1635_B322271

Comment: are you still with this trouble? 
Have you change the buildpath of the WSphere and the IDE?

Regards