# spring Exception when running application on WebSphere with java 8

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc

I got several `IllegalStateException`,`CannotCompileException` and `LinkageError` at the time of application running on WebSphere 9.0 java 8 . These this is stack trace of error :

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: javassist.CannotCompileException: by java.lang.LinkageError: org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyCreatorSupport
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JavassistApplicationContext.<clinit>(JavassistApplicationContext.java:61)
        ... 114 more
Caused by: javassist.CannotCompileException: by java.lang.LinkageError: org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyCreatorSupport
        at javassist.ClassPool.toClass(ClassPool.java:1120)
        at javassist.ClassPool.toClass(ClassPool.java:1063)
        at javassist.ClassPool.toClass(ClassPool.java:1021)
        at javassist.CtClass.toClass(CtClass.java:1259)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JavassistApplicationContext.<clinit>(JavassistApplicationContext.java:59)
        ... 114 more
Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyCreatorSupport
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassImpl(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:346)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:283)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor17.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
        at javassist.ClassPool.toClass2(ClassPool.java:1133)
        at javassist.ClassPool.toClass(ClassPool.java:1114)
        ... 118 more
```

and also i am getting `java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError` :

```
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp notifyServletContextCreated SRVE0283E: 
Exception caught while initializing context: {0} java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at java.lang.J9VMInternals.ensureError(J9VMInternals.java:141)
        at java.lang.J9VMInternals.recordInitializationFailure(J9VMInternals.java:130)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:88)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:437)
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:126)
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:104)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:258)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:204)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
```

And in `pom.xml` File, I have following dependency.

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
            <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.16</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Javassist -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javassist</groupId>
            <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
            <version>3.19.0-GA</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>[1.1.1,)</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging-api</artifactId>
        <version>[1.0.3,)</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4jVersion}</version>
        <!--<scope>provided</scope>-->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4jVersion}</version>
        <!--<scope>provided</scope>-->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4jVersion}</version>
        <!--<scope>provided</scope>-->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.14</version>
        <!--<scope>provided</scope>-->
    </dependency>
    <!-- Global Test -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
            <dependency>
        <groupId>com.ibm</groupId>
        <artifactId>ibmpkcs</artifactId>
        <version>8.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>       
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <showDeprecation>${maven.compiler.showDeprecation}</showDeprecation>
                    <showWarnings>${maven.compiler.showWarnings}</showWarnings>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    <debug>${maven.compiler.debug}</debug>
                    <optimize>${maven.compiler.optimize}</optimize>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
    </build>

  <properties>
        <spring.version>4.2.5.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <spring-ws.version>2.4.0.RELEASE</spring-ws.version>
        <spring-security.version>4.0.0.RELEASE</spring-security.version>
        <slf4jVersion>1.6.1</slf4jVersion>
        <maven.test.skip>true</maven.test.skip>
        <junit.version>4.8.2</junit.version>
        <hibernate.version>3.5.6-Final</hibernate.version>
   </properties>
```

i am using spring `4.2.5.RELEASE version` and `javassist 3.19.0-GA` version .

and in the web app, I can see following jar files after installing the application on WebSphere  `/WEB-INF/lib`

- `aopalliance-1.0.jar`
- `commons-io-1.4.jar`
- `jcl-over-slf4j-1.6.1.jar`
- `spring-aop-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar`
- `spring-expression-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar`
- `bcprov-jdk16-1.46.jar`
- `freemarker-2.3.16.jar`
- `log4j-1.2.14.jar`
- `spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar`
- `spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar`
- `commons-codec-1.4.jar`
- `ibmpkcs-8.0.jar`
- `slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar`
- `spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar`
- `spring-webmvc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar`
- `commons-fileupload-1.2.2.jar`
- `javassist-3.19.0-GA.jar`
- `slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar`
- `spring-core-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar`

also in `web.xml` i am using `org.springframework.aop.framework.JavassistApplicationContext`

```
<context-param>
        <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
        <param-value>org.springframework.aop.framework.JavassistApplicationContext</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<listener>
 <listenerclass>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

and in class path /`WEB-INF/classes/org/springframework/aop/framework` i have some javassist classes .

```
JavassistAopProxy$1.class                          
JavassistAopProxy$EqualsInterceptor.class                  
JavassistAopProxy$JavassistMethodInvocation.class  
JavassistAopProxy.class  JavassistAopProxy$AdvisedDispatcher.class          
JavassistAopProxy$ExProxyFactory.class                   JavassistAopProxy$MethodInterceptor.class          
JavassistAopProxyFactory.class  JavassistAopProxy$CompositeInterceptor.class       
JavassistAopProxy$FixedChainStaticTargetInterceptor.class  
JavassistAopProxy$StaticDispatcher.class         JavassistApplicationContext.class JavassistAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.class  
JavassistAopProxy$HashCodeInterceptor.class                
JavassistAopProxy$UnadvisedInterceptor.class
```

Any suggestions on this error? I have tried following methods to

1. class loader parent last method on server and application
2. Update spring to latest version
3. removed javascript jar files from `/WEB-INF/lib` path

I can't understand what is this error means. Any explanations and suggestions to solve this error. It was working fine in WebSphere 6 with Java 1.6

update :

```
mvn dependency:tree

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ myapp-parent ---
[INFO] com.test:myapp-parent:pom:6.2.0
[INFO] +- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.2:provided
[INFO] +- commons-logging:commons-logging-api:jar:1.1:provided
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] +- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.14:compile
[INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:4.8.2:test
[INFO] \- com.ibm:ibmpkcs:jar:8.0:compile
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Web Application Package 6.2.0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ myapp-webapp ---
[INFO] com.test:myapp-webapp:war:6.2.0
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:4.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:4.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.4:compile
[INFO] +- commons-io:commons-io:jar:1.4:compile
[INFO] +- commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload:jar:1.2.2:compile
[INFO] +- javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.5:provided
[INFO] +- org.freemarker:freemarker:jar:2.3.16:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:4.2.5.RELEASE:test
[INFO] +- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.21.0-GA:compile
[INFO] +- org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk16:jar:1.46:compile
[INFO] +- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.2:provided
[INFO] +- commons-logging:commons-logging-api:jar:1.1:provided
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] +- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.14:compile
[INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:4.8.2:test
[INFO] \- com.ibm:ibmpkcs:jar:8.0:compile
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Enterprise Application Package 6.2.0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ myapp-ear ---
[INFO] com.test:myapp-ear:ear:6.2.0
[INFO] +- com.test:myapp-webapp:war:6.2.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.6.1:provided
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.6.1:provided
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.6.1:provided
[INFO] +- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.14:provided
[INFO] +- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.2:provided
[INFO] +- commons-logging:commons-logging-api:jar:1.1:provided
[INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:4.8.2:test
[INFO] \- com.ibm:ibmpkcs:jar:8.0:compile
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO]
[INFO] my application...................................... SUCCESS [  9.465 s]
[INFO] Web Application Package ............................ SUCCESS [  0.104 s]
[INFO] Enterprise Application Package ..................... SUCCESS [  0.044 s]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 10.721 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-09-18T13:33:51+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 13M/245M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**Update**

And now i think the problem due to javassist file . I am loading a specific class using javassist in my code .org.spring.aop.framework.ProxyCreatorSupport is a class that will be loaded by the class loader . But i am getting some IllegalStateException , cannot compile exceptions when i deploy .EAR file to WebSphere .

Using ClassPool.getDefault(), I am looking up information from the system class path . Added the class loader that is handed over by the transformation method as an argument. I have appended class loader to Javassist's search path .

```
package org.spring.aop.framework;

import javassist.ClassPool;
import javassist.CtClass;
import javassist.CtConstructor;
import javassist.LoaderClassPath;
import org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext;

public class JavassistApplicationContext extends XmlWebApplicationContext {

    static {
        ClassPool classPool = ClassPool.getDefault();
        try {
            ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
            classPool.appendClassPath(new LoaderClassPath(classLoader));

            CtClass cc = classPool.get("org.spring.aop.framework.ProxyCreatorSupport");
            CtConstructor c = cc.getConstructors()[0];
            c.insertAfter("$0.aopProxyFactory = new org.spring.aop.framework.JavassistAopProxyFactory();");
            cc.toClass();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

It was working fine with java 1.6 WebSphere 8 . After update to java 8 WebSphere 9 , i am getting these kind of exceptions .I think Javassist `toClass()` causing exceptions in websphere . Also  `CtClass cc = classPool.get("org.spring.aop.framework.ProxyCreatorSupport");`making some linkage issues . Any suggestion now ?

Comment: With your current pom it is impossible that you are using 4.2.5 as there is no `spring-asm` dependency anymore for that version. So in short remove the `spring-asm` dependency.

Comment: will `spring-asm` dependency be a problem with `javassist` . i am getting the exception errors due to `javassist`?

Comment: If you include that jar it has to be from an old version. With that old version there are incompatible changes (things changed from class to interface etc.). so first cleanup your class path.

Comment: ok . can i clear the class path by clearing class caches ?

Comment: Also why are you asking the same question [again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45923219/java-exception-linkage-error-when-running-application-on-websphere-9-0-with-jav) and [again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46171296/spring-class-loading-issues-while-deploying-ear-application-on-websphere-9) and [again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46193022/javassist-and-aop-linkage-error-during-application-server-deployment-in-webspher)? You have answers and suggestions in all of them. You shouldn't start a new thread/question each day!

Comment: Just remove that dependency and reload the application. Also you are appearing to be using an ear make sure you don't have duplicate jars in different class loaders. Also what is this application context you are using? That isn't something from spring (afaik) .

Comment: i have one doubt . How can i ensure whether i have  duplicate jars in different class loaders ? i also took class loader verbose trace too . and `org.springframework.aop.framework.JavassistApplicationContext' am using from web.xml

Comment: Check your dependencies. I can see from where you are using it but what is it?

Comment: this `contextClass` parameter that points to the Spring class that implements the `ApplicationContext` . i can javassist  .class files from `/WEB_INF/classes/springframework/aop/framework/JavassistApplicationContext ` i have updated the question with class files

Comment: i have removed the spring-asm and cleared the class path .still getting same error . updated the pom.xml file . Any suggestions ?

Comment: Did you configure your web app in order to user web app class loader first?

Comment: did you mean parent last /first methods in WebSphere ? if not i didn't . can you please suggest how to configure that ?

Comment: Yes i meant in the websphere configuration where you "tell websphere" to use web app classloader as first classloader

Comment: yeah . i have tried it . still getting same exceptions .

Comment: @ Angelo Immediata @M. Deinum  i have updated the question with my java code too .

Comment: May you post your dependency tree?

Comment: @ Angelo Immediata updated with dependency tree .

Comment: Any suggestion  ? Still i am stuck with this exception error

Comment: Still i am facing same exception .  Any updates ?