# How to create shared libraries in WebSphere to share jar files

Tags: java, maven, websphere, classloader, javassist

I can see the class path from log files as

```
was.install.root = /IBM/WebSphere/AppServer
user.install.root = /IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/AppSrv01
Java Home = /IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/java/8.0/jre
ws.ext.dirs = /IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/java/8.0/lib:/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/AppSrv01/classes:/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/classes:/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/lib:/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/installedChannels:/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/lib/ext:/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/web/help:/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/deploytool/itp/plugins/com.ibm.etools.ejbdeploy/runtime
Classpath = /IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/AppSrv01/properties:/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/properties:/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/lib/startup.jar:/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/lib/bootstrap.jar:/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/lib/jsf-nls.jar:/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/lib/lmproxy.jar:/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/lib/urlprotocols.jar:/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/deploytool/itp/batchboot.jar:/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/deploytool/itp/batch2.jar:/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/java/8.0/lib/tools.jar
Java Library path = /IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/lib/native/linux/x86_64/:/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/java/8.0/jre/lib/amd64/compressedrefs:/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/java/8.0/jre/lib/amd64:/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/bin:/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/nulldllsdir:/usr/lib64:/usr/lib:
Orb Version = IBM Java ORB build orb80-20170207.00
```

and I have some jar files in `/WEB-INF/lib` path of application server and some class files in `/WEB_INF/class` path .

In `/WEB_INF/lib` path , I have following jar files .

```
aopalliance-1.0.jar
commons-io-1.4.jar
jcl-over-slf4j-1.6.1.jar
spring-aop-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-expression-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar
bcprov-jdk16-1.46.jar
freemarker-2.3.16.jar
log4j-1.2.14.jar
spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar
commons-codec-1.4.jar
ibmpkcs-8.0.jar
slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar
spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-webmvc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar
commons-fileupload-1.2.2.jar
javassist-3.19.0-GA.jar
slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar
spring-core-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar
```

I want to move `javassist-3.19.0-GA.jar` to shared library to avoid class conflict . I have read the steps to configure and adding the shared library in WebSphere from IBM . Now i want to know what should i write in shared library path ? Is it something like `${WAS_INSTALL_ROOT}/WEB_INF/lib/javassist-3.19.0-GA.jar` ? and should i remove `javassist-3.19.0-GA.jar` from /lib path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$WAS_INSTALL_ROOT will get you as far as /IBM/WebSphere/AppServer; the closest you can get to your app binaries with a default server variable is $USER_INSTALL_ROOT, which will get into profiles/AppSrv01, and app binaries are in the "installedApps" directory within that location.

That said, pointing to the application binaries in your shared library is a very bad idea.  If you don't want that jar to be loaded by the WAR class loader, then get it out of there and put it somewhere else.  I would note that I don't fully understand WHY you're putting it into a shared library (what is it conflicting with?), so maybe some clarification would help with that as well.

Comment: I posted a question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46272658/spring-exception-when-running-application-on-websphere-with-java-8?noredirect=1#comment79510314_46272658 . please check this . I want to avoid these exceptions by using shared library . You have any idea about this ?

Comment: Just putting it in a shared library isn't, on its own, going to help anything - by default, associating a shared library with a web module just adds it to the module's class loader (so you can theoretically manipulate class path order, but not the loader being used).  You can change up the order by using an isolated loader for the library or associating it with the app, but then you're introducing multiple instances of the library, so keeping the extra copy around becomes more of a risk than anything.

Comment: then what should i do to solve that exception ? i tried several methods . You have any idea about that exceptions ?

Comment: LinkageErrors tend to be pretty awful to diagnose, as the JVM's messages are basically useless - they're often caused by duplicate visibility, but usually across multiple class loaders, not just within one loader.  Semi-related, I answered another question that I just noticed was yours, regarding a tool that can check for duplicate classes in an app; I'd strongly recommend giving that a try.  There is literally no way to use two of the same class in a WAR, so there's no use case for including multiple copies of anything.

Answer (score 1):

In WebSphere you can create Shared Libraries for localizing or sharing dependencies among different applications. 
Here's IBM help document for the same.
Please add comment or inbox if you need help with the same.

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/tcws_sharedlib.html

And you should keep in mind that both the types of files (server shared library and application lib) will end up in the classpath for your application to read. If you provide two different versions in any combination, it can always produce ambiguity.