# How to create an isolated Classloader for loading all the class files in websphere 9?

Tags: java, java-8, websphere, classloader

I have some class files in `/WEB_INF/classes` folder and also some jar files in `/WEB_INF/lib` path . I am getting some `Linkage error` when i deploy `.ear` files . I think this error usually indicates that the *class has a dependency on another class* . isn't ?

Now i want to put these classes files in `/WEB_INF/classes` to a **isolated class loader** so they all get loaded together. I just want to know , Is this method is correct ? How can i create a isolated class loader in WebSphere 9 for my web app ?

Comment: You need to add full stack trace with the exception. `classes` and `lib` are loaded by the same classloader, so thats not the issue. To create isolated classloader, you do it on the server level so its different stuff. Just add full stack for a start.

Comment: I have posted different questions here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46272658/spring-exception-when-running-application-on-websphere-with-java-8?noredirect=1#comment79510314_46272658 . But still i can't solve this issue . That is why i am going classloader methods .

Comment: I don't see any way an isolated class loader is going to help.  An isolated class loader is used for shared libraries (so you'd most likely want to remove the stuff there from WEB-INF/classes), and in practice it basically just gives those classes their own class loader (with no parent, so it operates in a de facto "PARENT_LAST" manner).  I don't see why that would resolve a LinkageError.

Comment: ok @Jarid . Any other idea to solve linkage error ? i am getting these exceptions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46272658/spring-exception-when-running-application-on-websphere-with-java-8?noredirect=1#comment79510314_46272658 . I explained all the scenarios there . Any suggestions ?

Comment: Any updates or suggestions ?